# 'NoneType' object is not iterable for serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to pull data to create function from serializer but i am getting an error

**Models**

```
class Article(models.Model):

   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
   author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='articles')
   caption = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class ArticleTags(models.Model):

   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
   tag = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
   article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True, related_name='posttags')
```

**Serializers**

```
class ArticleCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images_set = ArticleImagesViewSerializer(source='images',required=False,many=True)
    tags_set = ArticleTagViewSerializer(source='posttags',required=False,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('images_set','tags_set','id')


    def create(self,validated_data):
     images = self.context['request'].FILES.getlist('images_set')
     articleinit = Article.objects.create(**validated_data)
     tags = self.validated_data.get('tags_set',None)
     for imageinit in list(images):
        m2 = ArticleImages(article=articleinit , image= imageinit )
        m2.save()
     for taginit in list(tags):
        m3 = ArticleTags(article=articleinit , tag = taginit)
        m3.save()
     return articleinit
```

This is the error with the line:

```
  File "C:server\accounts\serializers.py", line 146, in create
    for taginit in list(tags):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Why am i getting this error?

Comment: It means `tags` is `None`, so you can not enumerate over it...

Comment: is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
tags = self.validated_data.get('tags_set',None)
```

To:

```
tags = self.validated_data.get('tags_set',[])
```

Which will avoid trying to iterate over a None, and instead will iterate over an empty list (thus will have no affect)

Apologies for bad formatting, used my phone.